# Send text into textbox loaded in a website inside WebView

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a `WebView` and it can load a website, say http://www.google.com. Suppose the website has a textbox and when I click/touch it, the default Windows Touch Keyboard springs up.

I don't want to use the default keyboard as I'm creating my own custom keyboard. What I want is for the characters entered in my custom keyboard (implemented in the same `UserControl` along with the `WebView`) to send the entered characters into the currently selected textbox of a webpage loaded inside the `WebView`.

How would I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

If y want insetr text into some HTML element (input,textarea,etc), you may to use DOM and property innerHTML

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I don't know anything about HTML so can you give me a reference or explain how I can access the DOM when I know only the name of the `WebView` in C# ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx
this is example, when y have ID of element on HTML page, y can try to find example with name or class

Comment: `WebView` is not able to find the ID of the currently given-focus-to textbox/other control on the webpage at any instant of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the default behavior of input elements in Windows Store apps, including Web apps hosted inside WebView. There are no APIs for custom keyboards in Store apps, and you will not be able to prevent the keyboard from popping up at when a text-based input element is focused.

Comment: The default touch keyboard can be prevented from popping up by disabling it's service. I know there's no custom keyboard; I'm making one from buttons inserted into a `UserControl`.

Comment: Are you planning on distributing this app in the Store, or is it an LOB app?  Either way, this is a very bad way to go about this.

Comment: `a very bad way to go about this` Why ?

Comment: Because you can't depend on another machine disabling the touch keyboard service.  If they did, it would make other apps needing the touch keyboard useless until it was turned back on.  Unless this is an app intended only for personal use, you are running into big risks.  Furthermore, it definitely will not be certified by the store.

Comment: You're right of course but this is a single-system app and doesn't need to go though the store. What I want is a very unique setup exclusively designed for multiple users to operate together on a single large touch-enabled monitor.